# How to check if all non static public members of a struct are non const references

Tags: c++, c++20

I'd like to implement a concept to constrain a template type to be a struct where all non static public members are non const references.

For an example these structs should satisfy the concept

```
struct A
{
    int& i;
    std::string& s;
}

struct B
{
    int& i;
    std::string& s;

    void foo() { s = std::to_string (i); }
}

static_assert (isStructOfNonConstReferences<A> == true);
static_assert (isStructOfNonConstReferences<B> == true);
```

While these should not

```
struct C
{
    int i;
    std::string& s;
}

struct D
{
    const int& i;
    const std::string& s;
}

static_assert (isStructOfNonConstReferences<C> == false);
static_assert (isStructOfNonConstReferences<D> == false);
```

I'm not aware of any way to do that with C++ 20 tools, but maybe someone knows a trick to achieve that? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: There is currently no way to list or iterate the members of a class type in C++.

Comment: Seems your classes match [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)/[`boost_pfr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) requirements, to have basic reflection as tuple.

Comment: @Jarod42 Boost.PFR requires types to be *SimpleAggregate*, which includes having no reference members. [See limitations of Boost.FPR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_pfr/limitations_and_configuration.html).

Comment: @JanSchultke Amusingly, the techniques used by that primitive reflection stuff could detect some of this, as I think you can distinguish `struct { int x; }` from `struct { int& x; }` by how `X{}.x` vs `X&{}.x` vs `X const&{}.x` binds in a `[]` binding.